Question on abstract nonsingular curves
I am reading section 1.6 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. There he defines abstract nonsingular curve $C_K$ attached to a field $K$ which is finitely generated over another $k$ of transcendence degree $1$ whose points are DVR's of $K/k$ and the topology is the cofinite topology. In theorem $6.9$ he went to prove that $C_K$ is infact isomorphic to a nonsingular projective curve. He defines a map $\varphi: C_K\to Y$ (where $Y$ is a projective curve) and showed the induced maps on each local rings are isomorphic. Now using exercise 3.3 b) we will be done if we show that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. Here I am not able to understand how he claims directly this is injective and surjective (For surjectivity he said for any point $Q$ of $Y$ we can find a DVR R of $K/k$ which dominates $\mathcal{O}_Q$. But how does it follow $\varphi$ is onto? And also why can we always get such a DVR $R$?)

I am answering what I understood after reading again. First I will talk about surjectivity and then I will talk about injectivity.
The details of the map $\varphi$ is as it is in Hartshorne.
As it is mentioned in the book for a point $Q$ of $Y$ we consider the localization of the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_Q$ at a maximal ideal. Then there is an injective map(first embed $\mathcal{O}_Q$ into the integral closure and then compose it with the natural map of localization) from $\mathcal{O}_Q$ to this ring. Secondly this is a local ring is of dimension $1$ which is integrally closed and Noetherian. For Noetherian we have use theorem 3.9A of Hartshorne. So $\mathcal{O}_Q$ embeds inside this ring and moreover the unique maximal ideal of this ring corresponds to the maximal ideal (which we have localized) of the integral closure of $\mathcal{O}_Q$ and this must contract to the unique maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_Q$.(This last theorem follows from the result of integral extensions Corollary 5.8 of Atiyah-Mcdonald). Therefore indeed this ring dominates $\mathcal{O}_Q$. we can view this ring as a point $P(/ R_P)$ of $C_K$. And the way we have defined the map $\varphi$ indeed we get that $R_P\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\varphi(P)}$. Hence we get that $\mathcal{O}_Q\subseteq \mathcal{O}_{\varphi(P)}$. So finally we are done by Lemma 6.4 of Hartshorne.
For the injectivity part if we have $\varphi(P)=\varphi(Q)$ for two points $P$ and $Q$, then it follows that $R_P\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\varphi(P)}\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\varphi(Q)}\simeq R_Q.$
Please correct me if there is any mistake.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
